Deploy .Net Aspire project to an Azure VM
I am doing some research on .NET Aspire and have a few questions regarding it:

I'm working on a microservice architecture with each microservice having its own solution. Can I create a separate Aspire solution and reference all the microservices? Is it recommended? Because in every tutorial I saw, there is a single solution containing multiple microservices.

I've deployed all my services on 3 different Azure VMs. Can I deploy an Aspire project to a VM? If yes, I guess I would need an Aspire project on each VM to manage the services of a specific VM. Everywhere I see that the Aspire project is deployed on a container app, and it manages the microservices just like Kubernetes pods. Is there a way to have a centralized Aspire project deployed on a VM that manages all the services?

I am using ASP.NET Boilerplate in a few microservices. Does Aspire support ABP?




Really the whole reason to use Aspire is to have one .sln that orchestrates many distributed services that each end up on different platforms/vms/containers. See Aspire's orchestration documentation. You sort of lose the benefits of Aspire if all your services must stay in separate solutions. Think of Aspire as more of an opinionated framework that forces you to use certain conventions. It doesn't work if you structure the solution in a way that goes against those conventions. That said, you could probably move / copy those projects into a new Aspire solution and have it discover and orchestrate each one.
Deploying is sort of a separate concern. As stated in Aspire's documentation, ".NET Aspire projects are built with cloud-agnostic principles, allowing deployment flexibility across various platforms supporting .NET and containers." In theory, you could publish and deploy the resulting compiled software to anything. But the recommended approach is to deploy to a container since they are vastly more lightweight and scalable than VMs.
Possibly. However, Aspire is pretty opinionated. Some features of Aspire like service discovery and health checks might overlap with ABP's features. You may need to adapt some extension methods to get them to work together, and modify the ABP project's startup configuration to include Aspire's service defaults. May be better to pick one or the other. Or maybe move the business logic classes into a new project in an Aspire solution that's already put together the Aspire way.

